# How to ensure that Terminal runs when I start X?

Tags: raspbian, xorg, lxterminal

My ~/.xinitrc file is seemingly being ignored.
Has X changed fundamentally in recent years?

Comment: What exactly do u want to do? Open a terminal on booting up?

Comment: assuming you are in a single user solution you could make your edits to the global xintrc file in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc. the downside to this is that it will run your command for every user (this may or not be an issue for you).

Comment: what command do you use to start X?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are logging in via the default GUI [display manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_(program_type)), `lightdm`.  Different display managers have different attitudes toward using start up files such as `.profile` and `.xinit`.  Technically, they're not obliged to do either thing, since they aren't login shells, and you aren't calling `startx` or `xinit`.  This is approach taken by `lightdm`.

However, it (or rather, X itself) will execute `~/.xprofile` and `~/.xsession`.  The easiest thing to do is move your stuff into that.  There are other solutions to this problem online if you search "lightdm xinitrc".